# PyQt5 QTableview column resizing

Tags: python, pyqt5

Using a PyQt5 QTableView with 4 columns (1 hidden).  I need to fix the first and third column to a specific size and allow the middle column to resize (ie take up the rest of the space).  I attempted the following strategy but it does not yield what I am looking for:

```
self.icdDataView.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
self.icdDataView.setColumnWidth(3, 100)
hdr = self.icdDataView.horizontalHeader()
#hdr.setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
hdr.setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
#hdr.setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
self.icdDataView.setModel(mdl)
self.icdDataView.setColumnHidden(0, True)
self.icdDataView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
self.icdDataView.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
self.icdDataView.setColumnWidth(3, 100)
self.icdDataView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
self.icdDataView.selectRow(0)
```